# warning: format '%s' expects argument of type 'char *', but argument 2 has type 'int'

Tags: c, printf

I have this program that claims to convert a decimal number to hexadecimal. The issue is that the program throws the above warning and I don't know how to correct it. The return (variable identifier) is supposed to be a `%s` because what you want to display is a string.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int n = 0;
    char hex = '\0';
    const char * HEX_DIG = "0123456789ABCDEF";
    printf ("Enter a positive integer: ");
    scanf ("%d",&n);
    do{
        hex = HEX_DIG [n % 16] + hex;
        n = (int) n/16;
    }while ( n != 0 );
    printf ("\nHexadecimal= %s", hex);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: %s for a character array (string) but %c for a *single* char.

Comment: The variable `hex` is a single character, not a string of hexadecimal digits (which is probably what you want).

Comment: Your `hex` is a single character. It should be a string (i.e. a char array). Also you cannot use "+" to add a character to a string. You need strcat.

Comment: 'char hex = '\0';' - char, (int), not a C string, so compiler moans..

Comment: And just to clear up (or, admittedly, potentially cause) confusion, that one-character value i`hex` is promoted to `int` when passed to the variadic function `printf` (just in case you were wondering where that `int` in the warning message was coming from). Regarding the code, I strongly suspect that loop ain't gonna do what you hope it would.

Comment: It looks like you need to review a tutorial on strings in C. You've got problems with the basics here.

Comment: @wohlstad But `strcat` won't add a character to a string, either.

Comment: @SteveSummit you are right. I had in mind using a one character string for the concatination.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `%s` format token expects to be given a string which, in C, is a **pointer to** a `char` (or an array of `char`s).  You've provided it a `char` which, when passed to a function with variadic arguments (in this case, `printf`), gets promoted to an `int`.  That's what the compiler is complaining about.

Furthermore, even if your code was valid C, you'd be printing the integer backwards.

To print a `char`, you need to use `%c`.  The best way to incorporate that into your existing code would be to move the `printf` inside the loop:

```c
for (int k=0; k<sizeof(int)*2; k++) {
    hex = HEX_DIG[(n >> (sizeof(int)*8-4)) & 0xf]; // Move the high four bits all the way to the right and then mask them off.
    n <<= 4;  // Shift the next four bits into place.
    if ( hex != '0' ) { // No need to print leading 0's.
        printf("%c", hex);
    }
}
printf("\n");
```

To explain the `sizeof` calculations, let's assume that `int`s are four-bytes wide.  Then `sizeof(int)*2` would be eight which accounts for the eight sets of four bits.  `sizeof(int)*8-4` would be 28 and so we'd be shifting off all 32 bits except for the four highest.

Note that this code does ignore the case when `n` is zero.  In such a case, the loop would print nothing.

Backing up a bit, unless you're doing this as an exercise (perhaps a homework problem), I'd recommend not reinventing the wheel as `printf` already supports the printing of integers in hex format:

```c
printf("%x\n", n);
```